# How long does it take for a 20th level wizard to prepare his full allotment of spells?

Tags: spells, wizard, adnd-2e

A wizard requires 10 minutes of prep time per spell level to memorize a spell.

How long would it take for a 20th level wizard to prep his entire spell allotment?

Answer (score 11):

10×(5×1+5×2+5×3+5×4+5×5+4×6+3×7+3×8+2×9) = [1620 minutes](https://www.google.com/search?q=10*(5*1%2B5*2%2B5*3%2B5*4%2B5*5%2B4*6%2B3*7%2B3*8%2B2*9)), or about 27 hours. Neither *Mordenkainen's Lucubration* nor *Rary's Mnemonic Enhancer* are of any help in this matter unless obtained via the application of the *Enchant an Item* and *Permanency* spells (a wise investment of possible Constitution loss if allowed), in which case the latter spell can reduce the spell prep time to a single segment for all spells of 5th level and less, which results in a preparation time of 14 hours and 37 and a half minutes.

Comment: The wizard must also have a good night's sleep, so add another 8 hours onto that, maybe another night's worth since there non-stop studying for 27 hours might well trigger fatigue or exhaustion first. Having a 3rd level priest on hand to cast _Nap_ would be smart.